# How to create a subpackage in android studio

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio.

### Right now, my android Studio project only has a single package, the application package.  How do I create a subpackage ?

Currently, the package for the MainActivity.java  is:
**package** `com.davidgassner.plainolnotes.;`
I want the directory for the subpackage to be:     **package**`com.davidgassner.plainolnotes.data;`

When I created the subpackage using your's and Android Studio's instruction 
I got the following:
**package** `com.davidgassner.plainolnotes.com.davidgassner.plainolnotes.data;`
I am getting an indication from Android Studio that the above path is not correct.

Comment: Using your instructions I am not getting the proper sub-package path and Android Studio is indicating that there is a problem with that path (See my comments above):

Comment: I think you got me on the right path.  I was able to create the sub-project following your instructions without any indications of errors.  I appreciate your guidance.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

**Right click in your main package** -> **New** -> **Package** -> Give a name to your package and there you go.

If your main package is `com.davidgassner.plainolnotes` and you want to create `com.davidgassner.plainolnotes.data` , follow the steps above and when asked to input the package name, supply only "data". It will be created like this:

```
+ com.davidgassner.plainolnotes
                             + data
```

In the top left corner you can switch your perspective from `Android` to `Project` to see all your project structure:

[image]